# Caso de uso do conceito SRP em uma aplicação real

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando alguns conceitos de OOP e vejo bastante sobre a questão de SRP, "separar ações em classes etc". a nível de testes, decidi criar um pequeno sistema para cadastro de usuários afim de testar os conhecimentos, só que me deparei com algumas questões

> 1 - Devo separar a lógica de validação e a parte do CRUD em classes
>   separadas?
>
> 2 - É de responsabilidade do usuário validar a si próprio?
>
> 2.1 - A classe User pode ser responsável por "acumular" os erros da validação?
>
> 3 - O usuário é responsável por salvar a si mesmo?
>
> 4 - Como seria este exemplo com milhares de atributos? usar um loop
>   nos métodos setters?

O que concluí, com base nos estudos:

- Devo usar 3 classes, User, UserValidator e UserCRUD, pois no meu entendimento são "ações" distintas
- A classe User seria a mais "abstrata", relacionando a validação e a integração com o banco de dados.
- Devo criar uma segunda classe chamada UserValidator que seria responsável pelas regras de validação, podendo ser acoplada à alguma biblioteca de validação? (Respect/rakit)
- E por fim, criaria uma última classe chamada UserCRUD, que herdaria os métodos de outra classe chamada "crudModel", responsável pela integração com o banco de dados

Exemplo de código:

```
class User {

    private $name;
    private $age;

    function __construct () {

        $this->userValidator = new userValidator;
        $this->userCRUD = new userCRUD;
    }

    function setName($name) {

        if($this->userValidator->validateName($name))
            $this->name = $name;
    }

    function setAge($age) {

        if($this->userValidator->validateAge($age))
            $this->age = $age;
    }

    function hasErrors () {
        return $this->userValidator->hasErrors();
    }

    function Save () {

        $user_data['name'] = $this->name;
        $user_data['age'] = $this->age;

        return $this->userCRUD->create($user_data);
        // retorna true para salvo e falso para erro
    }

}
```

-

```
    class UserValidator {

    private $error_bag;

    public function validateName ($name) {

        if(strlen($name) > 5)
            return 1;
        else 
            $this->setValidationError('name', 'Nome deve ser maior que 5');
    }

    public function validateAge ($age) {

        if(is_numeric($age))
            return 1;
        else 
            $this->setValidationError('age', 'Idade inválida');
    }

    private function setValidationError ($error, $error_msg) {
        $this->error_bag[$error] = $error_msg;
    }

    private function getValidationErrors() {
        return $this->error_bag;
    }

    public function hasErrors () {

        if( empty($this->getValidationErrors()) )
            return false;
        else
            return $this->getValidationErrors();
    }
}
```

Chamada do código:

```
    $User = new User;
    $User->setName('Fulano de Tal');
    $User->setAge(50);

    if($User->hasErrors()) {
        // exibe os erros na tela
        print_r($User->hasErrors());

    } else {
        // salve o usuario
        $saveUser = $User->Save();
        var_dump($saveUser);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

### Em busca do SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)

Segue as respostas da suas perguntas.

#### 1 - Devo separar a lógica de validação e a parte do CRUD em classes separadas?

Sim. É melhor separar a validação da parte que faz as operações de CRUD, pois são operações distintas.

---

#### 2 - É de responsabilidade do usuário validar a si próprio?

Não necessariamente. Você pode criar um componente para validar um usuário, já que isso iria de encontro com o SRP.

#### 2.1 - A classe User pode ser responsável por "acumular" os erros da validação?

Complementando a resposta anterior: o componente que faz validação seria um lugar mais apropriado para essas informações.

---

#### 3 - O usuário é responsável por salvar a si mesmo?

É melhor criar uma classe para salvar um usuário, pois tudo fica mais separado. Quando um usuário salva ele mesmo o SRP está sendo violado, pois o objeto tem duas responsabilidades: conter as informações do usuário e persistir ele no banco de dados. Esse tipo abordagem se chama Active Record e ela acaba misturando as coisas, portanto é melhor evitá-la para poder seguir o SRP.

---

#### 4 - Como seria este exemplo com milhares de atributos? usar um loop nos métodos setters?

Pelo que entendi, a sua dúvida nessa questão é nos casos de muitos dados. Caso o seu objeto User tenha vários dados, você pode passar um array com os dados para evitar uma quantidade imensa de getters e setters. [Esta pergunta está respondida de forma mais detalhada aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333521/boas-praticas-para-classe-que-cresce-muito/333635#333635)

---

#### Seu exemplo da classe User

Percebi que seu código contém algumas dependências no objeto User:

```
function __construct () {

    $this->userValidator = new userValidator;
    $this->userCRUD      = new userCRUD;

}
```

Essa implementação poderia melhorar se você passar o objeto User para os objetos e não fazer ele recebê-los, por exemplo:

```
class UserValidator
{

    public function validate(User $user)
    {
        // Pegar os dados do objeto user e validá-los aqui
    }

}

class UserCrud
{

    public function save(User $user)
    {
         // Salva e edita o usuário
    }

    public function delete(User $user)
    {
         // Deleta o usuário
    }

}
```