# Boas praticas para classe que cresce muito

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, solid

Complementando uma pergunta que postei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333235/caso-de-uso-do-conceito-srp-em-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-real) há algum tempo, sobre um sistema para cadastro de usuários usando conceitos do padrão SOLID, um dos problema que me deparei foi a questão da classe User ser muito grande e pode ser muito variável, uma vez que um usuário pode ter diversas características, segue um "roteiro" de situação:

- Cada atributo tem seu setter/getter na classe User.
- Cada atributo tem sua regra de validação na classe userValidator.
- Cada atributo tem sua "definição" em um array associativo da classe
  userCrud.

Digamos que em outra situação um usuário possa ter atributos como: corDosOlhos, corDoCabelo e etc, eu teria que sempre estar alterando as classes acima, qual seria uma boa solução para isso?

Estrutura da classe User:

```
class User {

private $attributes;

function __construct() {
    $this->userValidator = new userValidator;
}

function setName ($param) {

    if($this->userValidator->validateName($param))
        $this->attributes['name'] = $param;
}

function getAttributes () {
    return $this->attributes;
}

function getAttribute ($attr) {

    if(isset($attributes[$attr]))
        return $this->attributes[$name];
    else throw new Exception("Attribute '{$attr}' does not exist");

}
```

}

Comment: Sempre que você acrescenta um atributo novo tem que alterar a classe UserValidator. Isso é uma violação do princípio O do SOLID. Tenha uma classe validadora por atributo. Sua classe UserCrud eu não entendi bem, seria legal postar um exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. sobre o userCRUD é simplesmente uma classe que faz a interação com o banco de dados, pega o objeto User e transforma em array e insere , por exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A validação

Para validar cada atributo será melhor ter um validador para cada valor. Tendo isso em mente, caso um novo atributo surja não é necessário modificar a classe.

Basicamente, os validadores serão passados para um validador principal:

```
class UserValidator
{

   private $validators = [];

   public function setValidator($attribute, $validator)
   {

      $this->validator[$attribute] = $validator;

   }

   public function validate(User $user)
   {

       $messages = [];

       foreach($user->getData() as $attribute => $value){

           // Verificando se um validador para o atributo existe
           if(isset($this->validators[$attribute])){
               $message = $this->validators[$attribute]->validate($value);

               // Caso contenha a mensagem de validação, ela será armazenada em um array
               if($message){
                  $messages[$attribute] = $message;
               }

           }

       }

       // Retornando as mensagens de validação para serem utilizadas
       return $messages;

   }

 }
```

---

#### Utilizando o UserValidator

Para utilizar a classe será necessário passar os validadores para ela. Como é possível notar, para adicionar uma nova validação basta configurar a classe com o método setValidator.

```
$userValidator = new UserValidador;
$userValidator->serValidator('name', new NameValidator);
$userValidator->setValidator('age', new AgeValidator);
$userValidator->setValidator('corDosOlhos', new CorDosOlhosValidator);
// Basta continuar configurando para cada novo atributo necessário.
```

---

#### A entidade User

Por fim, a entidade User iria trabalhar com um array para não ficar com uma quantidade imensa de métodos. Caso um novo atributo seja adicionado, a classe fica intacta. Segue a implementação:

```
class User
{

   private $attributes;

   public function __construct(array $attributes){

       $this->attributes = $attributes;

   }

   public function getData()
   {

      return $this->attributes;

   }

   // Exemplo de método que pode ser utilizado em outros contextos
   public function getUserAttribute($attribute){

       if(isset($this->attributes[$attribute])){
           return $this->attributes[$attribute];
       }

       throw new Exception('Attribute not found');

   }

}
```